# Graph Theory: Every graph has a unique potential

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let $G$ be a simple, connected graph. Define the potential of a graph as

$$V_S(G)=\sum_{i=1}^{g-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{g}\frac{\delta_{i\in S}\delta_{j\in S}}{d(u_i,u_j)}$$

where $S\subseteq \{1,2,...,g\}$, $g=|G|$, and $\delta_{i\in S}$ is $1$ if $i\in S$ and $0$ otherwise. For example, for the following graph

[image]

with $S=\{1,3,5\}$ we have $V=2$ since there are two paths between members in $S$ of length $2$ (which add $\frac{1}{2}$ each) and one path of length $1$ (which adds $1$). For a given $1<k<g$, define the set

$$\Omega_k=\{V_S(G):|S|=k\}$$

**Question:** For a given graph $G$ with a trivial automorphism group (more on this later), will there always be some $1<k<g$ such that $\Omega_k$ has a unique minimum?

For the example graph above (even though it does have a non-trivial automorphism) the set $S=\{1,3,5\}$ gives a unique minimum potential over all sets of cardinality $3$.

**Observations:** For a given $S$, we can calculate $V_S(G)$ in $O(g^4)$ time by employing [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) (which goes as $O(g^2)$) over all pairs of vertices (which also goes as $O(g^2)$). This implies that if $k\leq M$ or $g-k\leq M$ then we can determine if $\Omega_k$ has a unique minimum in $O(g^{M+4})$ time.

Of course, this doesn't mean much as for a given $M$ it is fairly easy to construct a graph $G$ such that $\Omega_k$ does not have a unique minimum for $k\leq M$ and $g-k\leq M$. Simply chain a bunch of [star graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)) with a high number of points together and it is not to hard to prove.

As to why we discard graphs with non-trivial automorphisms, it is obvious that the complete graph would be a counterexample to this conjecture. However, apart from $K_n$ (as well as some other graphs with very high degrees of symmetry like $K_{n,n}$) it would seem that most graphs with non-trivial automorphisms still admit some $k$ such that $\Omega_k$ has a unique minimum.

**Random Tests:** Testing this conjecture on random graphs (both with and without trivial automorphisms) has always led to unique minimums. In fact, it would seem that most graphs have several $k$ such that $\Omega_k$ has a unique minimum. It is only for highly symmetric graphs (like $K_n$ missing an edge) that you only get a single $k$ that works ($k=2$ in this case). But again, these graphs have non-trivial automorphisms and so do not have to be considered for the conjecture.